# jQuery change a div ID on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div which is hidden when a link is clicked (the link is actually an image) the hidden div displays. I then have a link in the hidden div to 'hide' that div again. What I want to try and achieve is the original image/link 'toggles' allowing the user to use that image to open and close the div. My code so far is as follows:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function controlFooterIcons(v){
            if(v==1) $("#rpacks_admin").show(50);
            else $("#rpacks_admin").hide(50);
        }

        function toggleIcons(v){
            if (v==1) $('#show_rpack').attr("id", "hide_rpack");
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#show_rpack").click(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    controlFooterIcons(1);
                    toggleIcons(1);
                });
                $("#hide_rpack").click(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    controlFooterIcons(0);                      
                });
        });
        </script>
```

and the HTML/PHP

```
<div id="rpacks_admin" style="display: none;">
<h5>Hello</h5>
<a href="#" id="hide_rpack">Close</a>
```

and the link that should 'toggle'

```
<a href='#' id='show_rpack'><img class='footericon'src='$BASE_URL/images/icons/recoverydisc.png' /></a>"
```

Comment: I don't think changing the id or using functions built on `if` statements is a good idea.

Comment: I'd agree with blender, you should really be changing class names or adding and removing classes

Comment: Ok but why is this not a good idea? And do you have an example of another way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$("#show_rpack").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    var theDiv = $("#rpacks_admin");
    if (theDiv.is(":visible")) { 
        theDiv.hide(50);
    }
    else { 
        theDiv.show(50);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, much more constructive than simply saying its not a good idea and giving no explanation or alternative

Comment: If you seek an explanation, I would tell you this: On page-load (document ready), in your original code, you attached two click handlers. One to all elements with id `show_rpack`, and one to all elements with id `hide_rpack`. The problem with this code is that on page-load, no elements with id `hide_rpack` exist, and the event handler is thus not bound. If you instead bind the handler to the element that you know exists on page-load, and modify its behavior based on a condition checked when it is triggered as in my code, the code will work as expected.

Comment: Furthermore, the first event handler, the one bound to `show_rpack` will not be magically unbound when you change the id of the element. Thusly, that event handler will be triggered whether you change the id or not.